# Make emacsclient open multiple files in separate windows

Tags: window, emacsclient

When I open multiple files at once with `emacs`, like `emacs file1 file2`, it opens the two files side-by-side (in different windows in the same frame). But when I do the same with `emacsclient`, it only shows the first one. The others are also opened but not visible. How do I get the emacs behavior with emacsclient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this behavior to be systematic, here's a way to modify the behavior of `server-visit-files` to take over the window configuration and split the window evenly into the files that are being visited.

```
(defvar server-visit-files-custom-find:buffer-count)
(defadvice server-visit-files
  (around server-visit-files-custom-find
      activate compile)
  "Maintain a counter of visited files from a single client call."
  (let ((server-visit-files-custom-find:buffer-count 0))
    ad-do-it))
(defun server-visit-hook-custom-find ()
  "Arrange to visit the files from a client call in separate windows."
  (if (zerop server-visit-files-custom-find:buffer-count)
      (progn
    (delete-other-windows)
    (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (let ((buffer (current-buffer))
      (window (split-window-sensibly)))
      (switch-to-buffer buffer)
      (balance-windows)))
  (setq server-visit-files-custom-find:buffer-count
    (1+ server-visit-files-custom-find:buffer-count)))
(add-hook 'server-visit-hook 'server-visit-hook-custom-find)
```

An improvement would be to make `C-x #` kill the window. I think this would require patching both `server-edit` to set a flag and `server-switch-buffer` to kill the window if this flag is raised.